# How convert the code defined workflow with GetExtension to XAML workflow with designer support

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have this code in code defined workflow (it works!):

```
    new Assign<ViewDataProvider>
    { 
        To = _viewDataProvider,
        Value = new InArgument<ViewDataProvider>(ctx =>
                     new ViewDataProvider(ctx.GetExtension<IServiceProvider>()) { Name = "my name"}) 
    },
```

I tried this solution as first step for support XAML serialisation:

```
    Value= ExpressionServices.Convert<ViewDataProvider>(ctx => 
           new ViewDataProvider(ctx.GetExtension<IServiceProvider>()))
```

but came exception "Expression of type 'Parameter' is not supported." 
So, how I can set Assign.Value in workflow designer with ctx.GetExtension() in expression? The other problem is how I can set the Name property in expression?